# npm test hangs after angular unit tests pass in Github Actions

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, github-actions, karma-jasmine

I added a step in my Github Actions workflow to run my Angular tests using the command `ng test`. The tests run and pass successfully but it never moves onto the next step in my workflow.

What have I tried:

- Adding the argument watch=false in the step so that "ng test" isn't watching for file changes.
- Setting singleRun to true in karma.conf.js

Nothing's worked so far and I'm not seeing any other resources that can help me solve this issue.

Here is a snippet of the step in my build-push.yml file:

```
- name: Run tests
  run: npm test -- --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

Here is a snippet of my karma.conf.js file:

```
reporters          : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
port               : 9876,
colors             : true,
logLevel           : config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch          : true,
browsers           : ['Chrome'],
singleRun          : true,
restartOnFileChange: true,
```

Here is the yaml file of the workflow:

```
name: Build PUSH only
on:
  push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
      REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
      BRANCH: ${{ github.ref_name }}
      CI: true

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the PR
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install Azure CLI
        run: curl -sL https://aka.md/InstallAzureCLIDec | sudo bash 
      - name: Install Angular CLI
        run: npm install --location=global @angular/cli@14.0.0
      - name: Install packages
        run: npm install
      - name: Build the UI
        run: ng build -c production
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test -- --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

[image: The above image is a screenshot of the workflow running in Github Actions. I expected "Post Set up Node" to run but it just hangs on the tests]

The above image is a screenshot of the workflow running in Github Actions. I expected "Post Set up Node" to run but it just hangs on the tests

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. Thank you all!

Comment: Can you please enable full debug on github actions - [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) - and set `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` in your Karma config and publish full logs?
It would be also nice to see whole yaml file of your workflow...

Comment: I'll go ahead and enable full debug! I've also added the yaml file in the question body above for you to view. Thank you @Michal

Comment: OK. So where are logs?
I would suggest to publish it as a gist.

Comment: Here's the link to view the logs which I published as a gist: https://gist.github.com/simonchn160/91aac08635daf873bfb1bc276d2a9a12 . It seems like the tests pass and complete successfully, but it's still hanging on that step in my workflow for some reason. Thank you @Michal

Comment: Can you try run it without chrome-headless?

Comment: I tried that already - unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue @Michal

Comment: Well, in your log there is also a problem with loading color-version for kjhtml reporter and since there is some undefined problem at the end of procedure i would try to run tests without it.

Comment: The yaml you show doesn't actually have the `--watch=false` in it. I confirmed with a test project that tests weren't finishing [without it](https://github.com/PdUi/github-actions-build-test/actions/runs/3889689558) and then were [with it](https://github.com/PdUi/github-actions-build-test/actions/runs/3889699408/jobs/6638183434). Is it possible you forgot to commit with the --watch=false flag in your build file?

Comment: In workflow log there was a `watch=false` option seted up -> [link](https://gist.github.com/simonchn160/91aac08635daf873bfb1bc276d2a9a12#file-workflow_log-txt-L9)...

Comment: @peinearydevelopment sorry, I accidentally left out the --watch=false flag in the snippet I pasted above, but yes, I had the watch=false flag in there already. My mistake, I've added it into the snippet above now!

Comment: I finally got it working! Turns out it had something to do with Karma Browerstack. Here's the link to the solution I found: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-browserstack-launcher/issues/195 @Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with Karam Browserstack. Seems like this is also affecting several people using Angular 14. The only workaround in place currently is to run `sed -i -z "s/ removeAllListeners()\n/ removeAllListeners();process.nextTick(() => process.exit(code || 0));\n/g" node_modules/karma/lib/server.js` in the workflow before the tests are executed. Link to this solution: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-browserstack-launcher/issues/195

Answer (score 1):

What worked in my case (.gitlab-ci.yml) was switching ChromeHeadless to Chrome. I didn't need the hack. Found that idea here https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3803#issuecomment-1204484192

It now works on trion/ng-cli-karma with simple:

```
- npm install
- ng test --no-watch --source-map=false --browsers=Chrome
- npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my local machine (so I'm not sure if it would work in github actions). `karma start` would run perfectly but `npm test` would hang. The reason is `ng test` is doing something that karma is not, I am unsure of what exactly since I don't have a lot of experience with angular, but I am guessing it is packaging the application using one of the `development` or `production` configurations from `angular.json`.

However what fixed the problem for me was generating the `karma.conf.js` file with angular's own command. Run in the root folder of your project

```
npx ng generate config karma
```

(or this if you have `ng` installed globally)

```
ng generate config karma
```